# powercli create snapshot if vm's datastore has more than %10 free space

Tags: powershell, if-statement, snapshot, powercli

Hi i'm workin over a script for days. I want to take vm snasphot if vm's datastore has requred space.

My script :

```
$myarray =@{}
$myarray = get-vm test | get-datastore | select-object @{N="DSFreespace"; E={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpaceGB)/($_.CapacityGB)*100,2)}}
$Treshold = "{0:n2}" -f 10

foreach ($Treshold in $myarray) {
if ($myarray -ge $Treshold){new-snapshot -vm test -name test123} else {
Write-Host "You cannot take a snapshot. Datastore free spce is lower than 10%" }
}
```

When i run script in shell it 
Also i composed another one for same thing, but no luck. when i use "-ge" condition, script always take snapshot of vm, regardless free space percent (i tried it many different numbers, other than original  treshold)

İf i use "-gt" condition, script never take snaphot, regardless free space percent.

I also tried another script for same thin, same results. Also, same thing for -lt and -le conditions

```
$vm = get-vm test
$Treshold = "{0:n2}" -f 10
$DSFreespace = get-vm $vm| get-datastore | select-object @{N="DSFreespace"; E={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpaceGB)/($_.CapacityGB)*100,2)}}
if($DSFreespace -ge $Treshold){new-snapshot -vm $vm -name test123} else {
Write-Host "You cannot take a snapshot. Datastore free space is lower than 10%" }'''
```

What is wrong, how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does it work if you change your variable $Treshold to `$Treshold = 10.00`? Or, alternetavily, `$Treshold = 10.00 -as [system.double]` Side note; your foreach in the fir example is quite peculiar but that might be secondary at his point.

Comment: Sorry, Nothing changes :(

Vm's datastore is Currently has 16% free space.  When i edit and execute script  as you said, it takes snapshot. Changing treshold value 20, 30 or 80 doesn't change anything. It still take snapshot.

When i seperately execute variables, their values are :

$myarray = get-vm test | get-datastore | select-object @{N="DSFreespace"; E={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpaceGB)/($_.CapacityGB)*100,2)}}

DSFreespace
-----------
      16.14

$Treshold = 10.00 -as [system.double]  gives :

10

or

$Treshold = "{0:n2}" -f 10   gives ;

10.00

i'm stucked :/

Answer (score 0):

I Solved problem by adding `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty DSFreespace`  to $dsfreespace parameter.

Before that script fails due to output result comes with   Property Label as :

> Cannot compare "@{DSFreespace=16.12}" to "10.00" because the objects
>   are not the same type or the object "@{DSFreespace=16.12}" does not
>   implement "IComparable". At line:5 char:5
>   + if (($dsfreespace -gt $treshold)) {new-snapshot -vm $vm -name test123} else {
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSObjectCompareTo

Correcting code as below solved all the problem. It takes only result value (in this case 16.12), not with property label (DSFreespace)

```
 ForEach ($vm in (get-datastore -VM $vm) | ForEach {$_.VM}) {
$vm = get-vm test
$treshold = "{0:n2}" -f 10
$dsfreespace = get-datastore -VM $vm | select-object @{N="DSFreespace"; E={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpaceGB)/($_.CapacityGB)*100,2)}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DSFreespace
if (($dsfreespace -gt $treshold)) {new-snapshot -vm $vm -name test123} else {
Write-Host "You cannot take a snapshot. Datastore free space is lower than 10%" }
}
```